# How can I mock the results of the GMail API?

Tags: google-app-engine, gmail-api

We are using the GMail API and developing an application on top of it. Ideally I would like to have some golden emails to test the analytics engine against. This way I can develop the analytics engine without having to worry about fetching the emails and hence without a network connection. What is the best way to achieve this? I noticed that App Engine (which we use) now allows you to mock DataStore/memcache etc. and run nosetests, but I don't know how to do this across local appserver restarts.

Answer (score 1):

The `Mock` class provided by [googleapis/google-api-python-client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/blob/main/docs/mocks.md) looks like a good candidate for your use case.

```py
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.http import HttpMock

mock = HttpMock('mock-email-list.json', {'status': '200'})
gmail = build('gmail', 'v1', http=mock)
response = gmail.users().messages().list(userId='me').execute()
print(response)
```

Where `mock-email-list.json` content is of the form

```json
{
   "messages":[
      {
         "id":"abcd",
         "threadId":"abcd"
      },
      {
         "id":"efgh",
         "threadId":"abcd"
      },
    ],
    "resultSizeEstimate":2
}
```

As a side note, after your test has run, you can also check what url the mock has been used for (by the gmail client):

```py
assert mock.uri == 'https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages?alt=json'
```

Answer (score 0):

The Gmail API nor the client libraries provide special functionality for mocking email fetching. You'll need to build out the mocks on your own.

Answer (score 0):

As a follow on from Arnaud's answer, the [googleapis/google-api-python-client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/blob/main/docs/mocks.md) `HttpMock` is helpful, I found `RequestMockBuilder` to work better for my use case.

```py
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.http import RequestMockBuilder

def read_response(filename):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as file:
        return file.read()

mock = RequestMockBuilder({
    'gmail.users.messages.list': (None, read_response('tests/unit/data/list_messages.json')),
})

build = build('gmail', 'v1', requestBuilder=mock)
```

The mock class allows you to pass a dictionary mapping API methods to appropriate responses. Unlike `HttpMock`, the builder expects responses as a JSON formatted string so a helper function may be required.